# onActivityResult is not called

Tags: android, android-intent, null, arrays

I need to send a byte array from an Activity to another Activity. I have something like this :
`Activity1` - > `Activity2` - > `Activity1`

In Activity2 I make a photo and I want to send the `byte[] imageData` to Activity1 to display it. For this, in Activity2 I have :

```
Camera.PictureCallback mPictureCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
       public void onPictureTaken(byte[] imageData, Camera c) {

           if (imageData != null) {
               takephoto=1;
               prefsEditor.putInt(TAKEPHOTO, takephoto);
               prefsEditor.commit();

               System.out.println("imageData in TakePHoto"+ imageData);
               Intent mIntent = new Intent();


               Bundle b = new Bundle();
               b.putByteArray("imageData", imageData);

               mIntent.putExtras(b);

               setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
               finish();

           }
           mCamera.startPreview();
           mPreviewRunning=true;
       }
   };
```

In `Activity1`, in `OnActivityResult()` I have this :

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            takephoto = myPrefs.getInt(TAKEPHOTO,0);
            System.out.println("OnActivityResult"+resultCode);  
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK )

                        if (takephoto == 1){
                Toast.makeText(this, "11",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                 BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                                options.inSampleSize = 3;

                                byte[] imageData = data.getByteArrayExtra("imageData");

                                System.out.println("imageData in Photos"+ imageData );

                                Bitmap myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                imageData.length, options);

                                Matrix mat = new Matrix();
                                mat.postRotate(90);
                                bitmapResult = Bitmap.createBitmap(myImage, 0, 0, myImage.getWidth(),
                myImage.getHeight(), mat, true);

                                myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
        }
```

The problem is that in `Activity1` `onActivityResult` is not called and I can't see where is my mistache. I'm working in Netbeans and I tested this code in Eclipse, and it works fine. Can anyone help me?

Comment: use onActivityResult() for that not resume() of Activity.

Comment: I used onActivityResult() but it is not called. I put in it the same code as on onResume().

Comment: How did you start `Activity 2` form `Activity 1`?

Comment: If you start Activity2 using startActivityForResult() then onActivityResult() definitely called.

Comment: And also I have a doubt about your Intent on onResume() because its not the intent from Activity2. Its the activity1 Intent.

Comment: In your `onActivityResult(int req,int res, Intent intent)` check the request/result codes and get the extras of the passed intent.

Comment: @user370305 From Activity1 to Activity2 I use startActivityForResult() but I still don't get the message from OnActivityResult, it is not called. I added my onActivityResult code.

Comment: How large is the byte array? Have you checked the logcat for errors?

Comment: @David Wasser imageData.lenght is about 8700. I don't get errors in logcat, the only problem is that OnActivityResult is not called. My code works in Eclipse, but I'm working in Netbeans and in Netbeans is not working.

Comment: If you say this works in Eclipse, but not in NetBeans, I would assume it isn't a code issue. Somehow NetBeans is packaging up the APK in a different way than Eclipse. You can probably compare the 2 generated APKs and try to see what is different. Maybe theres a file missing or a library missing

Answer (score 1):

Look in the documentation of putExtras :

> Add a set of extended data to the intent. The keys must include a
>   package prefix, for example the app com.android.contacts would use
>   names like "com.android.contacts.ShowAll".

Instead of putting a bundle in the intent :

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putByteArray("imageData", imageData);

mIntent.putExtras(b);
```

You could try to but directly the bytearray :

```
mIntent.putExtra("imageData", imageData);
```

**Why onActivityResult isn't called :**

When you set result you use the code FOTO_MODE :

```
setResult(FOTO_MODE, mIntent);
```

But in the onActivityResult, you check the code :

```
resultCode == RESULT_OK
```

You should do that :

```
if (resultCode == FOTO_MODE) {
     // then all your stuff of getting data from the intent.
}
```

And instead of using System.out.println("OnActivityResult"+resultCode);
use :

```
  Logd.d("Myclass", "OnActivityResult"+resultCode);
```

Comment: I tried this too, but it seems that onActivityResult() is not called. So I don't have the correct intent from Activity2, I have the intent of Activity1 which returns null. I don't see where is the problem, why onActivityResult is not called.

Comment: I still don't get the message from onActivityResult(). Here is how I call Activity2 from Activity1 Intent i = new Intent(Photos.this, com.Orange.MakeVisits.TakePhoto.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 2); There is something wrong here ?

Comment: I put the same code on Eclipse and it works fine. But on Netbeans it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my application (I still don't understand why `onActivityResult()` wasn't calling). In `Activity2` I put :

```
String stringData=Base64.encodeToString( imageData, Base64.DEFAULT);
prefsEditor.putString(STRINGDATA, stringData);
prefsEditor.commit();
```

and in `Activity1` I get `imageData` from `SharedPreferences` like this :

```
String stringData = myPrefs.getString(STRINGDATA, "stringData");
byte[] imageData = Base64.decode(stringData, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and like this I can receive the `byte[]`.